# Увеличить количество текста через цикл

Tags: javascript, jquery

Ребят помогите.
Как мне через цикл

```js
$(".btn-insert-txt").on('click', function() {
  var count = $(".select-menu-count").val();
    var align = $(".form-menu-align").val();
    var float = "text-align:";
  var border = "border:none;"
    var editBlock = "$('.edit-block')";
    var display = ",'block'";
    var closeTag = ";";
  var ulClass = "menu";
  var flex = "display:flex";
  var justifyContent = "justify-content:"+align+"";

  var ul = $("<ul class="+ulClass+" style="+flex+closeTag+justifyContent+"></ul>");
    var menu = $("<li><a href='/' class='link-" + align +"' " + onclick + " style=" + float + align + closeTag + border +
        ">text</a></li>");

        $(ul).append(menu);
        $(".preview").append(ul);

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="modal-menu-container">
<div class="modal-insert-txt">
<div class="header-modal">
<h2>Добавить</h2>
<span class="close-modal" onclick="closeModalMenu()"></span>
</div>
<hr>
          <span>Количество ссылок</span>
           <div class="form-group">
          <select class="select-menu-count">
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        
          <span>Выравнивание</span>
          <div class="form-group">  
          <select class="form-menu-align">
            <option value="left">Слева</option>
            <option value="center">По центру</option>
            <option value="right">Справа</option>
          </select>
        </div>

         <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn-insert-txt">Вставить текст</button>
      </div>
      </div>
        </div>
       
        <div class="preview">


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

увеличить количество append.
У меня есть select и в options у меня числа с 2 до 8. В js у меня есть переменная, которая отвечает за добавление ссылки с текстом. Как мне сделать, чтобы если я в options выбрал 6, то мне добавилась не 1 ссылка, а 6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(".btn-insert-txt").on('click', function() {
  var count = $(".select-menu-count").val();
  var align = $(".form-menu-align").val();
  var float = "text-align:";
  var border = "border:none;"
  var editBlock = "$('.edit-block')";
  var display = ",'block'";
  var closeTag = ";";
  var ulClass = "menu";
  var flex = "display:flex";
  var justifyContent = "justify-content:" + align + "";

  var ul = $("<ul class=" + ulClass + " style=" + flex + closeTag + justifyContent + "></ul>");
  var menu = "<li><a href='/' class='link-" + align + "' " + onclick + " style=" + float + align + closeTag + border + ">text</a></li>";
  for (let i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
    ul.append(menu);
  }
  $(".preview").append(ul);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="modal-menu-container">
    <div class="modal-insert-txt">
      <div class="header-modal">
        <h2>Добавить</h2>
        <span class="close-modal" onclick="closeModalMenu()"></span>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <span>Количество ссылок</span>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="select-menu-count">
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
          <option value="4">4</option>
          <option value="5">5</option>
          <option value="6">6</option>
          <option value="7">7</option>
          <option value="8">8</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <span>Выравнивание</span>
      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="form-menu-align">
          <option value="left">Слева</option>
          <option value="center">По центру</option>
          <option value="right">Справа</option>
        </select>
      </div>

      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn-insert-txt">Вставить текст</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="preview">


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```